# How to register changes in XML feed structure

Tags: xml, xsd

Hi I am working on an project where I need to register changes to XML feeds. XML feeds are generated from a third party website and I am interested if the structure of the feed changes. I don't mind if the value of a field changes but I do need to register the structure changes because of scripts running on the website. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
  <branch>
    <employee id="001">
       <name>Name 1</name>
       <designation>Engineer</designation>
     </employee>
    <employee id="002">
       <name>Name 2</name>
       <designation>Engineer</designation>
     </employee>
   </branch>
</company>
```

vs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
  <branch>
    <employee id="001">
       <something>Value</something>
       <name>Name 1</name>
       <designation>Engineer</designation>
     </employee>
    <employee id="002">
       <something>Value</something>
       <name>Name 2</name>
       <designation>Engineer</designation>
     </employee>
   </branch>
</company>
```

The files I am working with are much larger ( > 15000 lines) than the examples and changes in the feed could be as little as 'product' to 'Product'. The program registering the changes will be running on a server and performe a daily check.

I thought about converting the XML feed to a XSD file and storing the old version. That way I can daily generate a new XML file, convert it to XSD and comparing the old and the new version. But I am not sure this is the right way to go.

So my question is: **Does anyone know how to tackle this problem efficiently?**

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you describe is not how XML-based communication is supposed to work.

***Communication is built upon shared understanding.***  That understanding in XML-based communication is typically built upon a schema that defines the structure of the XML.  The schema becomes a contract against which you can write your code.

If there is no schema and the shared understanding is only that XML is being exchanged (and that the structure can change in any way allowed by XML), then your processing of the XML has to be extremely generic.  It has to be at the level of elements and attributes, because the shared understanding allows nothing more.  You're then operating in the realm of a generic XML parser.

If your shared understanding may include prior XML documents, as appears to be the case, yes, you can identify differences.  The issue, however, is what to do about those differences.  The differences will only be useful if you restrict their nature.  If you're expecting a MISMO mortgage application document and you receive a WIPO patent application, the differences will be vast and your options, nil.

Finally, if you do restrict the nature of the differences, how will you express that?  The answer is that you'd write a schema, which brings us right back to where you really should have been all along in order to conduct successful XML-based communication.

---

**Update based on comments**

If you merely want to identify differences between two XML documents,

- you might find [XML-based diff tools](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=xml%20diff%20tool) to be helpful, or
- you could create and compare lists of element and attribute names for
  the two XML documents.  Merely identifying new element or attribute names
  would be simple to do in XSLT or any language with a SAX library.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response! After reading your answer I think my question is not 100% clear on what I am trying to achieve. I don't aim to automatically deal with the differences between the files, but I just want the program to notify me where exactly the third party made changes. How to cope with the problem will be done by hand.

Comment: So the program would receive an old and a new file (in a format that works best) and return the lines where changes were made to the structure of the XML feed. Hope this clarifies the problem